# Linq Join hierarchy (one to many)

Tags: c#, linq, join, entities

I have 3 entities, Computer, Monitor and PortNumber. The entity monitor has a foreign key which references the entity computer while the entity PortNumber has a foreign key which references the entity Monitor. The following rules apply

- A computer can have many monitors but a monitor can only belong to
  one computer.
- A monitor can have many many port numbers but a port
  number can only belong to one monitor

I want to write a Join to to show the number the number of monitor and ports(monitor ports) for each computer. I am able to join two entities with the groupjoin but can't figure out how to add the 3rd entity.

```
var v = Ports.GroupJoin(Monitors, c => c.ComputerId, m => m.ComputerId, 
       (c, m) => new{c, m})
      .select(s => new {
           Computer = c.ComputerProp, 
           Monitors = m.Sum()});
```

How can I add the 3rd entity?
Here is some  executable code: http://dotnetfiddle.net/L1TBgJ

Comment: This is much easier to do/to read in the query syntax.

Comment: what do you mean please?

Comment: Have added an answer so I have more space to show. It may be what you need please advise.

Comment: http://dotnetfiddle.net/9LTYsT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the associations set up correctly in your EF Model you shouldn't need the joins at all. You should be able to do this simply as:

```
var v = Computers
        .Select(c => new {
             Computer = c.ComputerProp,
             Monitors = c.monitors.Count(), // note: not Sum(),
             Ports = c.monitors.Sum(m => m.ports.Count())
        });
```

I do notice in your test script where you are using objects, you are not instantiating the monitors and ports arrays and setting them to the objects you added. If you're using code-first EF for this (as I suspect you are), those values will be set when actually issuing the query against a database.

Comment: Wow. Thank you! You were right. I am using code-first EF and I did not have to do the joins.

Comment: This is cool. I am more used to LINQ and I think you have to jump through a couple more hoops to get it that succinct. Never tried EF, but might have to now :) .

Answer (score 1):

```
var v =
    from c in Computers

    // First outer join.
    join m in Monitors on c.ComputerId equals m.ComputerId into monitor
    from m in monitors.DefaultIfEmpty()

    // Second outer join.
    join p in Ports on m.PortId equals p.PortId into port
    from p in port.DefaultIfEmpty()

    // Group by the computers
    group new { m, p } by new { c } into g
    select new 
    {
        Computer = g.Key.c,
        Monitors = g.Select(i => i.m).Distinct().ToList(),
        Ports = g.Select(i => i.p).Distinct().ToList(),
    };
```

I think this is the kind of thing you are looking for. The second join means that you will need to make sure you call distinct on those items not included in the grouping. If the collection of ports exists on the monitor object. Then you will just need to nest the second part of the query.

If the ports are a collection on the monitor and you want to flatten them to link to computers. I think something like this should do it.

```
var v =
    from c in Computers

    // First outer join.
    join m in Monitors on c.ComputerId equals m.ComputerId into monitor
    from m in monitors.DefaultIfEmpty()

    // Group by the computers
    group new { m } by new { c } into g
    select new 
    {
        Computer = g.Key.c,
        Ports = g.Select(i => i.m).SelectMany(i => i.Port).ToList(),
    };
```

Comment: Thanks! this helps.I get errors at the group by lines (Cannot convert lambda expression to type System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer <TKey>' because it is not a delegate type)

Comment: I have noticed a small bug in the group by that might help. But without your exact code it is hard. If you can, please create a http://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: http://dotnetfiddle.net/tgkQVb I have changed the code slightly to make it easier in the output to see what is happening and it looks right to me, the correct links are there? Maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Thank you. But computer 1 has 2 monitors. How come only one shows up? Similarly for comp4

Comment: http://dotnetfiddle.net/Z86jj9 this is because not all monitors had a port. So this required an outer join. Whereas every computer did have a monitor. So you needed to include null entries to the right of the join. Sorry for the late reply. I hope in all of this fiddling, you have learned a lot :) .